# export declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I want to make an dynamic dependent dropdown (when I select a Chantier in 1st select the 2nd select will fill with ouvrages of Chantier)

**payer.blade.php**

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Chantier:</label>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="chantier" @change="getOuvrage()">
      <option value="0">Select Country</option>
      <option v-for="data in chantiers" :value="data.id"
        >@{{ data.chantier }}</option
      >
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Select State:</label>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="state">
      <option value="0">Select State</option>
      <option v-for="data in ouvrages" :value="data.id"
        >@{{ data.ouvrage }}</option
      >
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/Vue.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

**Vue-js code**

```
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    },
    data(){
        return {
            chantier: 0,
            chantiers: [],
            ouvrage: 0,
            ouvrages: []
        }
    },
    methods:{
        getChantier: function(){
          axios.get('/api/getChantier')
          .then(function (response) {
             this.chantiers = response.data;
          }.bind(this));

        },
        getOuvrage: function() {
            axios.get('/api/getOuvrage',{
             params: {
               chantier_id: this.chantier
             }
          }).then(function(response){
                this.ouvrages = response.data;
            }.bind(this));
        }
    },
    created: function(){
        this.getChantier()
    }
}
```

**SalarieController**

```
public function getChantier()
{
    $data = Chantier::get();
    return response()->json($data);
}

public function getOuvrage(Request $request)
{
    $data = State::where('chantier_id', $request->chantier_id)->get();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

**Routes\wep.php**

```
Route::get('payer', function () {
    return view('salarie.payer');
});
```

**Routes\api.php**

```
Route::get('getChantier', 'SalariesController@getChantier');
Route::get('getOuvrage', 'SalariesController@getOuvrage');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the way you are attempting to implement this directly into the blade file. But I can tell you how to build a Vue component in Laravel, which might help you get past the error you're receiving and clean up your blade files.

I have not tested this, but it's your code as a Vue component:

**/resources/js/components/PayerForm.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Chantier:</label>
            <select class="form-control" v-model="chantier" @change="getOuvrage()">
                <option value="0">Select Country</option>
                <option v-for="data in chantiers" :value="data.id"
                >{{ data.chantier }}</option
                >
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select State:</label>
            <select class="form-control" v-model="state">
                <option value="0">Select State</option>
                <option v-for="data in ouvrages" :value="data.id"
                >{{ data.ouvrage }}</option
                >
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'PayerForm',
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        data(){
            return {
                chantier: 0,
                chantiers: [],
                ouvrage: 0,
                ouvrages: []
            }
        },
        methods:{
            getChantier: function(){
                axios.get('/api/getChantier')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        this.chantiers = response.data;
                    }.bind(this));

            },
            getOuvrage: function() {
                axios.get('/api/getOuvrage',{
                    params: {
                        chantier_id: this.chantier
                    }
                }).then(function(response){
                    this.ouvrages = response.data;
                }.bind(this));
            }
        },
        created: function(){
            this.getChantier()
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Also, axios should already be loaded by default in Laravel via the bootstrap.js file, which is imported by the app.js file.  This includes automatically setting the CSRF token so you don't need to manage that for post/put/delete requests. You can check it out for yourself.

Register the component:

**/resources/js/app.js**

```
// this should include axios by default
require('./bootstrap');

// import the Vue library
import Vue from 'vue';
window.Vue = Vue;

// ... any other imports or declarations

// register your custom Vue component
Vue.component('payer-form', require('./components/PayerForm.vue').default);

// intialize your root component (some people use #app instead)
const root = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
});
```

Your blade file, assuming it's an `@include()` in a parent blade file that extends a layout loading the necessary styles and scripts, and assuming that layout includes your `<div id="root">...</div>` element as wrapper.  Ultimately, there's probably no need for it's own file anymore since you can just add the tag to the parent blade file.

**payer.blade.php**

```php
<payer-form></payer-form>
```

I hope this helps and good luck!

**EDIT:** 
Oh, and don't forget to compile your assets with mix! 
`npm run watch` or `npm run dev`, etc. when you make changes.